# How can implement foreign key in admin and model

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

```
                     Table1                                            

             sett_ num  |  Sett_typ                  

           -----------------------------            

              2014232          N                                         

              2014232          S                             

              2014232          O      

                 Table2
        stt_type_code | stt_typ_name
         ----------------------------
            N            Normal 
            S            OPTIONS 
            O            Index
```

this how the database looks for two table, here in table 1 i need display "Normal instead of N by referring the Table 2"

I have achieved this but the problem is the field i have made this change is not searchable and filters are not working properly

so I need to implement foreign key here can please you help me to solve this problem.

the model and admin look like this

```
Model.py(table 1)

class DLVR(models.Model):
      sett_type = models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=False)
      sett_num = models.CharField(max_length=7, editable=False) 

   Model.py(Table 2)

  class Sttlmnt_typ_Master(models.Model): 
        stt_typ_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, editable=True)
        stt_typ_name =  models.CharField(max_length=35, editable=True)
```

Admin.py

```
 class DLVRAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       list_display = ('sett_num','sett_type')
       search_fields=['sett_num','sett_type']
       def sett_type_display(self, obj):
           if Sttlmnt_typ_Master.objects.filter(stt_typ_code=obj.sett_type).first(): 
              sett_type = Sttlmnt_typ_Master.objects.filter(stt_typ_code=obj.sett_type).first()
              return sett_type.stt_typ_name
          else:
             return obj.sett_type
```

This is the way i need to implement in foreign key way can anyone help? and please give me examples in model and admin.

Comment: sett_type in DLVR models is unique or not  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `primary_key` parameter to `Sttlmnt_typ_Master.stt_typ_code` and then change `DLVR.sett_type` to foreign key:

```
class Sttlmnt_typ_Master(models.Model): 
    stt_typ_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    stt_typ_name =  models.CharField(max_length=35)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.stt_typ_name

class DLVR(models.Model):
      sett_type = models.ForeignKey(Sttlmnt_typ_Master)
      sett_num = models.CharField(max_length=7)
```

Admin will be as simple as:

```
class DLVRAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['sett_type', 'sett_num']
    search_fields=['sett_num','sett_type__stt_typ_name']
```

To set raw data to `DLVR.sett_type` (for example while import from CSV) add `_id` to field name:

```
DLVR.objects.create(sett_type_id='O', sett_num='2014232')
```

Comment: to the dlvr table I am importing values from a file if when i gave foreign key to that field I can't able to import data to that field from file @catavaran

Comment: See updated answer. You can assign raw text data to that foreign key field without any problems.

Comment: can you please show me where should i do this because i have one program called ftp.py which is doing the import process

Comment: I don't know how you doing import.  Just replace `dvlr.sett_type=somevar` with `dvlr.sett_type=somevar`.  The only you need to do is add `_id` to the field name.